# Region plot in the $xy$-plane of $f(x,y,z) < 0$

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I want to plot the region in the $xy$-plane which satisfies $f(x,y,z) < 0$, where $z$ can take values in the range [-1, 1]. How do I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Have you looked at `RegionPlot3D`?

Comment: [This example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html#1630733011) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @m_goldberg. As Roman gave an explicit example of how to it. This will solve my problem for now! But I am wondering if I can do it in general for functions of more than 3 variables and I still want a 2D Regionplot.

Answer (score 3):

In general, for each $z$ value, the projection of the contours of $f(x,y,z)$ onto the $xy$-plane will be different, so there is no single "region in the $xy$-plane which satisfies $f(x,y,z) < 0$". All you can do, I think, is look at contour plots for a sequence values of $z$. Here are two examples of how you might make such a sequence. Since you didn't supply an example of `f`, I will use this one:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^3 - z^2
```

#### SliceContourPlot3D

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
  f[x, y, z], {"ZStackedPlanes", 5},
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1},
  RegionFunction -> (f[#1, #2, #3] < 0 &),
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z",}]
```

[image: 3d_plot]

#### Projection onto 2D contour plots

```
GraphicsColumn[
  Table[
    ContourPlot[f[x, y, z], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
      PlotLabel -> Row[{"z = ", z, "\n"}],
      Contours -> Range[-5, 0],
      ContourShading -> None,
      ImageSize -> Medium],
   {z, Subdivide[-1, 1, 4] // N}]]
```

[image: 2d_plots]

Answer (score 1):

As @mgoldberg says, do a `RegionPlot3D` and view it flat from above (projecting out the $z$-axis):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^3 - z^2;
RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] < 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]
```

[image]

In this way you can see which $(x,y)$ values allow $f(x,y,z)<0$ for any $z\in[-1,1]$.

Using @ChipHurst's suggestion seems a bit more tricky and gives a poor quality plot:

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[Exists[z, 0<z<1 && f[x,y,z]<0], {x, y}],
  PlotRange -> {{-3,3},{-3,3}}]
```

[image]